# Screen lock on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint

I just upgraded to Linux Mint and noticed that when I close my laptop and then re-open it, there is no screen lock with a password prompt the way there is with Linux Ubuntu. Does Mint cinnamon have this feature? If so, how do I enable it? If not, is there an application I can download that will add this tool?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, these controls belong to `Brightness and Lock` or `Power option` buttons. If you cannot find them (Cinnamon is quite minimal) you may try:

```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-tools,
```

then launch from the applications panel `dconf-Editor`, and navigate to `org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power` and likewise for the screen lock. This will surely work.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently I am not the first person to discover this bug(which poses a **serious security risk**). But upon Googling the problem, I found a Linux forum where somebody mentioned an app called [**xscreensaver**](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/) which when installed and then activated, does exactly what I wanted(and needed mind you!). I did a systems settings check initially and it showed that the screen lock was on, but it wasn't working properly.

You can download and install it using Software Manager(click the gear icon in the lower left of your homescreen and scroll down to find it). Search for "xscreensaver", click *install*, and then type "xscreensaver" into the search bar. Once the new window pops up it will display the menu and the screen lock option is right there in the lower left hand corner.
Hope this helps others with the same problem! 8-)